# How to create a constant for the value of next year

Tags: c#, date, switch-statement, constants

I want to create a constant that is the value of next year. The purpose is to use the constant in a switch-case statement.

```
private const string filterThisYear = "= " + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Year);
private const string filterNextYear = "= " + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Year + 1);
```

The compiler complains, "The expression being assigned to 'filterThisYear' must be constant" and in the switch statement I get "A constant value is expected".

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you really need a compile time constant? If you want a non changeable value, you could make it `readonly`: `private static readonly int ThisYear = DateTime.Now.Year`

Answer (score 3):

"This Year" and "Next Year" are relative concepts by definition.

A constant is a value that is set at **compile time** and never changes.

"This Year" means 2016 as of this writing. When someone reads this "next year", "this year" will be 2017.

As far as the switch statement is concerned, this is a well known limitation. I am guessing you tried doing this:

```
switch (year)
{
    case DateTime.Now.Year:
        //Some code here
}
```

The compiler must have told you that it required a constant, so you decided to try to create one as shown in the question, which, as you now know, won't work for the aforementioned reasons.

It has to do with how the switch is compiled and executed and far beyond the scope of the question. Suffice it to say, it's not possible.

Use an if statement instead.